# mspaint.exe from php not opening window

Tags: php, exe

I am trying to open `mspaint.exe` window from PHP.

I am using the following function:

```
function run_exe() {<br>
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");<br>
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run("mspaint.exe", 3, true);<br>
}
```

Now I see that `mspaint.exe` process is added in task manager.
However it is not opened in a window.

How can I get it to be opened in an actual window?

I am using php 7.0 on IIS windows 10.

Comment: A web server is implemented (most usually) as a Windows Service and as such runs as a different user than you with its own isolated desktop. If it runs an application you will not see it or be able to interact with it.  Look in the all-users tasklist and you will likely see mspaint.exe instances.  You should explain exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I do see it in the task list.
What I would like is to see its window and interact with it.
However you say it is not possible.
Maybe it is possible using a different approach?
For example with using javascript instead of php?
Or running it on my windows user service?

Thanks.